# Disable input field for certain situations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have an input with angular directives.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-disabled="formReadOnly" data-ng-model="item[item.fields[0].name]" data-ng-keyup="comboBoxNDCOptions(2, 69, item[item.fields[0].name], 'searchNdc')" />
```

I want to add logic so that if a certain situation occurs the input field will be disabled. (un-editable)

So inside the input I'm trying to add the following:

```
{{true ?  'ng-disabled="true"' : ''}}
```

it should always evaluate to true in this case and thus add `ng-disabled="true"`.

However its not functioning as expected:

```
<input {{true ? 'ng-disabled="true"' : ''}} type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-disabled="formReadOnly" data-ng-model="item[item.fields[0].name]" data-ng-keyup="comboBoxNDCOptions(2, 69, item[item.fields[0].name], 'searchNdc')" />
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You can check some condition on `ng-disabled`. You can replace x==y with your logic that will evaluate to either true or false.

```
<input ng-disabled="x==y?true:false" type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-disabled="formReadOnly" data-ng-model="item[item.fields[0].name]" data-ng-keyup="comboBoxNDCOptions(2, 69, item[item.fields[0].name], 'searchNdc')" />
```